# How can I change keyboard layout on the login screen in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I was unlucky enough to send my Win-10 machine into sleep with a Russian keyboard activated. Since then I'm can not enter my pin since it's uses Latin letters. After googling I was shocked to learn that this problem is something known to the community for years, [the

official advise][1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cannot-login-my-windows-10-computer-cause-the/ab1b3b6c-bfcd-49f9-b16d-762a47959e22) I found is to activate software keyboard.
The thing is that I'm failing to see how to switch languages even with on-screen keyboard, since `Win` + `Space` is not working. This advise from the same thread:

> Found a workaround. English characters can be typed by holding Fn+Ctrl+Alt+letter. C and X don't work for some reason, but the rest are ok.

Seems to be working, however I have @ symbol in my password and have no idea how can I enter it.

So my question to the community is - how can I switch back to English layout being stuck at login page in Windows 10 (or enter symbols needed somehow else)?

[image]

Comment: DOUGH!  Perhaps Microsoft should not have fired all of their testers and relied on unit testing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + keycode using the *numeric keypad* to put in the password. E.G., <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> is `@`. Add `0`, `0`, before [the ASCII code](https://www.asciitable.com/).

It is far easier to just *remove* a **local** password using a utility such as [chntpw](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6967-chntpw.html), [Kali Linux](https://www.aurodigo.com/2019/05/how-to-remove-windows-10-login-password-using-kali-linux.html) or [Ubuntu](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/reset-windows-10-password-with-ubuntu.html).

After removing the password,

- Log in (no password required);
- Reset the keyboard;
- Go to the [User Accounts](https://winaero.com/how-to-make-windows-10-ask-for-user-name-and-password-during-log-on/) and put in a password for your account. If you have [Group Policy set to require a new password](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-policy), you may need to change the password, or that setting.

*Caveat:* This will *not* [reset a Microsoft (remote) password](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-or-reset-your-windows-password-8271d17c-9f9e-443f-835a-8318c8f68b9c).

Comment: this is just god damn amazing - I've googled that people are encountering this exactly problem for years without it being fixed on the microsoft side.

Comment: @shabunc, users will be in a worse bind with Windows 11, which apparently *requires* a Microsoft account to install... so no easy fix with local password. Of course, that might be considered more secure. A *totally* secure device is one that cannot be used -- at all.